# How to connect QnA Service on qnamaker.ai to an azure chatbot using Bot Service?

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I’ve created a QnA Service using qnamaker.ai and when I proceed further to create a bot using the Bot Service, I cannot because the upon searching there’s no option like Bot Service (Preview) as mentioned in the tutorials. Instead  I’m presented with the following:
• Web App Bot
• Functions Bot
• Bot Channels Registration

Comment: Have a look to the documentation please... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-quickstart you will see that you can found QnA template at least in Web App Bot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Azure, there are 3 services related to Bot:

1. Web App Bot
2. Functions Bot
3. Bot Channels Registration

Web App Bot and Function Bot are both part of Bot Service:

> Bot Service provides the core components for creating bots, including
>   the Bot Builder SDK for developing bots and the Bot Framework for
>   connecting bots to channels.

Simply put, Bot Service will host a **Web App / Functions Bot** in Azure and let you config channels or edit the code online.

**Bot Channels Registration** is for projects where the developer creates their own web app project based on Bot Builder SDK and deploy the web app to Azure/AWS/Google Cloud Platform. In Azure's Bot Channels Registration, the developer can link their web app's url to Azure and enable channels to communicate to their bot. In summary, this scenario enable more flexiblity in development and hosting.

In your case, you can create a **Web App / Functions Bot** use QnA Bot template. Once created,  in Application Settings > under App settings > Find *QnAKnowledgebaseId* & *QnASubscriptionKey*,
[image]
replace the two fields from the information in QnA service. [image]
Save the update and your Bot should use the QnA service you published.

Comment: Great answer!  

fyi: your MicrosoftAppPassword is exposed in the image you shared.